# Date in a form and validate

Tags: php, date

I am a little stuck here how to write a code for current date of the server and validate them.

So basically on one file is the form.php and i have to write the code for current date of the server in dd/mm/yy and this can be edited by the user. The date should appear in a form format for example on the web browser should appear date: [23/9/2012].

and on the other file which is the process.php I have to validate the date.

so for my form.php this is what i wrote so far:

```
<html>
<body>
 <?php
    if (isset ($_POST["date"])){
    $date = date("d/m/y"($_POST["date"]));
    echo $date;
    }
?>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="Date" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

what it appear on the web browser for date is only date:[date] just the word date but not the date. I've been stuck for an hour for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a regex:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['date']) && !empty($_POST['date'])) {
        $date = trim($_POST['date']);
    }

    $regex = '/^((([1-2][0-9])|([1-9]))/([2])/[0-9]{4})|((([1-2][0-9])|([1-9])|(3[0-1]))/((1[0-2])|([3-9])|([1]))/[0-9]{4})$/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $date)) {
        $disp_date = $date;

        //update the date in db
        $error = '';
    }
    else {
       $error = 'Invalid date format<br />';

       //get last date from db
       $disp_date = $date_from_db;
    }
    ?>
    <?=$error?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" value="<?=$disp_date?>" name="date" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Date" />
    </form>
```

How the regex works:
DD/MM/YYYY:
DD must be 1-31, MM 1-12 and YYYY a 4 digit num.

Edit: Fixed the problem with February.

Comment: Yes, but I just realised that it has a problem. It does not check if the month is 2, so to disallow DD as 30 or 31.

Comment: Hei Manolis, what do you mean by disallow DD though?

Comment: DD stands for day, february can have 29 days max, with the change I made a date like 30/2/2005 is invalid now.

Comment: There is a function *checkdate*

Comment: To be fair, there WAS a February 30th once. I don't know if there will ever be another one, but being able to represent that date might be important to some people, such as on a website that catalogs historical events.

Answer (score 1):

try formatting it something like this

```
   <?php
      $date = new DateTime();
      echo $date->getTimestamp();
      echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['date']) && strtotime($_POST['date'])){ # date validation
       $date = $_POST['date'];
   } else {
       $date = date('d/m/y');
   }        
?>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date?>" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you alexander, one quick question though, why we put "else", isn't else clause executes when the condition of if else statement is false?

Comment: @TylerMatema you can omit it, its just to set default value for `date` input field as today's date

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current date and display like this...

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$today = date("j, n, Y");
?>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $today?>"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and you can learn validate date from this link
[check date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

Comment: Thank you Raj, I over think myself doing this code and I can't believe it can be a simple code. I could just insert $date = date("d, m, y") and just echo it out in the value, I didn't know that -_- thank you so much raj, I keep learning new things everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You should rearrange your program like this:

```
<html>
<body>
 <?php
    if (!isset ($_POST["date"])){
        $date = date("d/m/y");
    else {
        $date = $_POST["date"];
    }
?>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
Date: <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you will let the user see the current time server at the first page load, and the edited one afterwards.

Comment: Hi Hernan, thank you so much, works like I wanted to, but one question, why we put the "else" though? isn't else clause executes when the condition of if else statement is false? I am sorry, im still beginner and get confuse often :S

Comment: What I did was:  If the user have not given the date, bring it from the system.  If not (else) use the date that the user gave.