# Data not saving to both tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am attempting to save user details to a database, I give sign up success but when I check my database only the User table is receiving the data. I do know my code is kind of messy but I am a newbie after all, here is the PHP, I cannot see any errors in the INSERT it seems to match my table name and fields. I am trying to make both the User table and the Member table be populated but at the moment only the User table is getting the data. Sorry I posted this earlier but included the wrong code so I deleted the post and here I am again.

```
if (isset($_POST["u"])) {
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("db_conx.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $ln = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['lastName']);
    $fn = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['firstName']);
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    $m = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['m']);
    $ci = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ci']);
    $pc = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['pc']);
    $rs = $_POST['relationshipStatus'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];
    $_POST['accountType'] = 0;
    $accountType = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['accountType']);

    //   $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT Userid FROM User WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT emailAddress from Member WHERE emailAddress = '$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if (u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == "" || m == "" || ci == "" || pc == "" || d == "") {
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0) {
        echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0) {
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
        exit();
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
        // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
        $cryptpass = crypt($p);
        include_once ("randStrGen.php");
        $p_hash = randStrGen(20) . "$cryptpass" . randStrGen(20);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Member (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, 
                    `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`, `dateOfBirth`)       
                VALUES('$fn', '$ln', '$g', '$e', '$ci', '$c', '$pc', '$rs', '$m', '$d')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO User (`Userid`, `username`, `password`, `accountType`) VALUES ('$uid','$u','$p','$accountType')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

When I echo out the INSERT into Member statement I get the following even though I populate every field on my form

```
INSERT INTO Member (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`, `dateOfBirth`) VALUES('', '', 'Male', 'test11@hotmail.com', '', 'Lebanon', '', '', '', '')signup_success
```

Comment: Uh… `"$asdf"` is the same as `$asdf`, so why bother with a string?

Comment: Sorry? I do not follow

Comment: echo out your $sql query string to check what it's trying to insert into the Member table. You could even paste that query into phpmyadmin to check if the query is valid or what error it gives.

Comment: For debugging echo out all your $sql strings to see if they contain what you expect. If you still don't find anything, after each query do `if (!$query) echo mysqli_error($db_conx);`

Comment: thanks for writing code that changes my name from what it actully is to what you think it should be.

Comment: @Dagon are you talking about the lastName and firstName arrays? and I have echoed what it is trying to insert, even though I populate every field on the form it is trying to insert the following                                                               INSERT INTO Member (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`, `dateOfBirth`) VALUES('', '', 'Male', 'test11@hotmail.com', '', 'Lebanon', '', '', '', '')signup_success

Comment: There are billions of names that are not just ascii a-z

Comment: Ok I will get round to changing that just trying to get the data in the tables first

Comment: I know this isn't an immediately productive comment, but why all of this, when you could be using Django?

Comment: hmmm, what's `'')signup_success` at the end of the string?

Comment: the signup_success is echoed at the end of my php, which would normally display a message using ajax telling the user they have registered successfully

Comment: @dimadima its more of a university project and I have been given guidelines to do my project this way :(

Comment: @Joey93, that's the pits.

Comment: do you think the problem could be with the replace function I keep using seeing as even though I fill in information in the form it still shows '' as empty the only fields working seem to be drop down lists and the email field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do - forgive the coding standard, I've been coding all day and I'm rather tired
Also, try to kill the page as you hit each error instead of saving them for later - once the page is killed, no further code is processed (it's read by the server, but not processed)
Just makes more sense to me - personal preference!

```
if (isset($_POST['u'])) {
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("db_conx.php");
    $lazy = array(
        'u' => 'username',
        'ln' => 'surname',
        'fn' => 'forename',
        'g' => 'gender',
        'c' => 'country',
        'ci' => 'city',
        'pc' => 'post code',
        'rs' => 'relationship status'
    );
    foreach($lazy as $what => $show) {
        $_POST[$what] = isset($_POST[$what]) && is_string($_POST[$what]) ? mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($db_conx,$_POST[$what])) : null;
        if(empty($_POST[$what]))
            exit("You didn't enter a valid ".$show);
        ${$what} = $what;
    }
    if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16)
        exit("Username must be between 3 and 16 characters");
    if (ctype_digit($u[0]))
        exit('Username cannot begin with a number');
    $e = isset($_POST['e']) && filter_var($_POST['e'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? trim($_POST['e']) : null;
    if(empty($e))
        exit("You didn't enter a valid email address");
    if(filter_var($_POST['d'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false)
        exit("You didn't enter a valid mobile number");
    $d = $_POST['d']; // Seeing as you're intent on creating variables for variabled data..
    /*
    Need to see how users enter their date of birth before I can properly secure that..

    If using <input type='date' ..>
    if(!preg_match('/[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/', $_POST['d']))
        exit("Invalid date of birth");
    */
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql1 = "SELECT `Userid` FROM `User` WHERE `username` = '".$u."' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql1) or exit(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query))
        exit("That username is already in use");
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql2 = "SELECT `emailAddress` FROM `Member` WHERE `emailAddress` = '".$e."' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql2) or exit(mysqli_error($db_conx));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query))
        exit("That email address is already in use");
    // Begin Insertion of data into the database
    // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
    $cryptpass = crypt($p);
    include_once("randStrGen.php");
    $p_hash = randStrGen(20) . $cryptpass . randStrGen(20);
    // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO `Member` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `gender`, `emailAddress`, `city`, `country`, `postCode`, `relationshipStatus`, `mobileNumber`, `dateOfBirth`) VALUES('".$fn."', '".$ln."', '".$g."', '".$e."', '".$ci."', '".$c."', '".$pc."', '".$rs."', '".$m."', '".$d."')";
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql3) or exit(mysqli_query($db_conx));
    $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO `User` (`Userid`, `username`, `password`, `accountType`) VALUES (".$uid.",'".$u."','".$p."','".$accountType."')";
    mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql4) or exit(mysqli_query($db_conx));
    echo "Account created"; // Or whatever success message you have
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the validate date I needed that

Comment: Not a problem. Has the rest helped, or are you still receiving issues?

Comment: I still seem to be getting issues, I echoed out the INSERT into Member statement and it only seems to be trying to insert the gender which is a drop down list and the country, the email seems to be present too even though I populate every field of the form I think some of the data is being replaced somewhere

Comment: Alright, I'll make a small edit to my code, try it and see what you get this time

Comment: Thank you I got it working this way I found out where I was going wrong

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help where I could. Sorry I couldn't of any more help to you

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again but would you be able to help me with validating the date, at the moment I have the date type as text so they can enter their own date

Comment: Aye, no problem. You can use HTML's date input (input type='date'). You can use the RegEx posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545631/date-in-a-form-and-validate <-- there